# single for-loop runtime explanation problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity, big-o, runtime

I am analyzing some running times of different for-loops, and as I'm getting more knowledge, I'm curious to understand this problem which I have still yet to find out.
I have this exercise called "How many stars are printed":

```
for (int i = N; i > 1; i = i/2) System.out.println("*");
```

The answers to pick from is 

`A: ~log N
B: ~N
C: ~N log N
D: ~0.5N^2`

So the answer should be A and I agree to that, but on the other side.. Let's say `N = 500` what would `Log N` then be? It would be 2.7. So what if we say that `N=500` on our exercise above? That would most definitely print more han 2.7 stars? How is that related?

Because it makes sense to say that if the for-loop looked like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

it would print `N` stars.

I hope to find an explanation for this here, maybe I'm interpreting all these things wrong and thinking about it in a bad way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is this different from your prior question? [Asymptotic running time of for-loops](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/253578/asymptotic-running-time-of-for-loops)

Comment: This has nothing to do with asymptotic running times.

Comment: That option only makes sense if the base-2 logarithm is meant, not the base-10 logarithm.

Comment: What base are you assuming to get Log 500 = 2.7? and does that base appear anywhere in your code? N.b. you are only ever a constant factor different with logs of different bases

Comment: @Caleth the logarithm base _does_ appear in the code: `i = i/2` the base is two because the loop is reversing repeated multiplication by two.

Comment: base2 log is implied in the code, but logn 500 = 2.7 implies n = 10. The question I posed and the comment @KilianFoth made are making the same point, I just phrased it as a question not a statement

Comment: What would this question's answer be good for? I would cry if i saw such a gross for loop in a codebase.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You've overlooked the key characteristic of the **logarithm base**.

Because `i` is divided by 2 in each iteration, the running time is logarithmic with base 2. And

> log<sub>2</sub>(500) ~ 8.9

What you are looking at is

> log<sub>10</sub>(500) ~ 2.7

(logarithm with base 10)

By the way, the reason why the base is often omitted in runtime discussions (and your calculator probably doesn't have a button for log<sub>2</sub>) is that due to the mechanisms of logarithmic math, a different base corresponds to a constant factor and thus is not relevant when you're ignoring constant factors anyway. It can be calculated easily:

> log<sub>a</sub>(x) = log<sub>b</sub>(x) / log<sub>b</sub>(a)

Comment: This makes total sense, so it's actually just my lack of knowledge about logarithms. Thanks for the simple and clear answer.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Borgwardt. Any chance you could give the example above with N=500. How can I calculate that on a calculator with only log base 10?

Comment: @owwyess you divide the log10 result by log10(2)

Comment: Sorry I had confused myself and divided with log10(10). Thanks all.

Comment: The constant factor mentioned in the last paragraph is about 3.322 for base 2.  I.e. you need ~3.3 digits of binary for one digit of decimal. Or if you rather, a 33 digit binary is ~10 digits in decimal.

Comment: Put another way... integer division by two is a binary bit shift.  500 = 111110100,  nine digits.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Michael Borgwardt's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/253658/31260), the tilde character in front of each answer should be read as "proportional to". So if you doubled N (say, from 500 to 1000), you would see that the run time (or, in this case, number of stars printed) would increase by a factor which would be equal to (log1000 / log 500), which is independent from which base you use.

Comment: I always understood tilde to mean approximate, not proportional. Essentially, `~` is a shorthand for `≅`.

Comment: *Proportional to* is the [`∝`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221d/index.htm) symbol not `~`! The `~` is used to indicate equivalence relations or *approximate* equalities (see wikipedia's page about [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#As_an_equivalence_operator)).